# Material to absorb very low frequency radio

Tags: materials, telecommunication, radio

Is there any material that will absorb very low frequency radio light? I know that stealth aircraft use radar absorbant materials in their design that absorb radio light best at certain frequencies, but I cannot find any information on materials that are explicitly stated to absorb very low frequency radio light.

I am not looking for any aspect of geometry such as faraday cages - only materials.

Comment: I've tried an RF absorptive material at 63MHz, and it still wasn't enough frequency to do anything.  I can't imagine anything being absorbed in the kHz region.

Comment: ... maybe try a coil tuned to that frequency.... Might absorb a few dB's of the wave, while making the remaining wave propagation very skewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a chunk of material will absorb electromagnetic radiation if 1) its characteristic impedance is close to that of a vacuum (to minimize reflections) and 2) if its impedance contains the right amount of ohmic resistance, so as to dissipate the radiation into heat and not re-radiate it.

that said, to interact significantly with EM radiation of any wavelength requires (ideally) that the size of the interacting object be a significant fraction of the wavelength of that radiation. This means that to absorb centimeter-range radar requires something like a centimeter of thickness to the absorbing layer.

Different rules apply if you are interested in just reflecting away the incident EM waves. In this case, a faraday cage will work.